# Use of pattern for template suggestion doesn't work in hook_theme()

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-theming

I'm trying to implement pattern and template suggestion but It doesn't work.
Here is the implementation of  `hook_theme()` with my pattern:

```
$theme['nm_home_page_zone'] = array(
  'pattern' => 'nm_home_page_zone__',
  'arguments' => array('nodes_content' => array(), 'nodes' => array()),
  'template' => 'zone-contenu',
),
```

And I call `theme()` with the following code:

```
$output .= theme(array('nm_home_page_zone__'.$rowZone->model.'_'.$rowZone->weight, 'nm_home_page_zone__'.$rowZone->model, 'nm_home_page_zone'), array(), array());
```

I got 2 template files (zone-contenu.tpl.php and zone-contenu--one.tpl.php) in my theme and my module (just to be sure).
The pattern and template suggestion should use zone-contenu--one.tpl.php in my case, but it doesn't work.

What I'm missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the answer (which is pretty simple though) : the template file **must** be named as the theme hook (key) 
So the changes are in the hook_theme :

```
$theme['zone-contenu'] = array(
  'pattern' => 'zone-contenu__',
  'arguments' => array('nodes_content' => array(), 'nodes' => array()),
  'template' => 'zone-contenu',
),
```

And that's it ! You're good to play with pattern :)
Keep in mind you can use dynamic template with theme() with a string like that :

```
theme('zone_contenu__fun__here', $hello);
```

In this example Drupal will automatically try to find zone-contenu--fun--here.tpl.php then zone-contenu--fun.tpl.php and finally zone-contenu.php
If you want to control the order of suggestion, give an array like above (FIFO) :

```
$output .= theme(array('nm_home_page_zone__'.$rowZone->model.'_'.$rowZone->weight, 'nm_home_page_zone__'.$rowZone->model, 'nm_home_page_zone'), array(), array());
```

Hope this help !

Comment: According to http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/48302/use-of-pattern-in-hook-theme the pattern isn't actually used. Therefor you should name your template(prefix) the same as the theme hook.